# Dangers of position:relative and left/top

Tags: html, css, css-position

If I'm using position:relative; with several elements, are there any problems i should watch out for?

Like with position:absolute; which will not work on different monitors?

Example:
`<img src="blah.png"/ class="someClass">
    <img src="blah.png"/ class="someClass">
    <img src="blah.png"/ class="someClass">
    <img src="blah.png"/ class="someClass">`

Css:

`.someClass{
position:relative;
top:20px;
left:40px;}`

Comment: What's with all the slashes in the `<img>` tags?

Comment: Mr Lister: Don't really know, wasn't there when I posted it.

Comment: in html5 those slashes meant the end tag is not required and the content between the start and end tag is presumed to be blank.just one thing.those slashes come at the end of all the inline method callings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to watch out for is `z-index`.Everything else will work fine.

> See here for [help](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
>
> and click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more info.
>
> compatibilty issue help [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/37-css-absolute-and-fixed-positioning/)